# How to install Oracle XE for windows32 properly?

Tags: oracle11g

I have downloaded and installed Oracle XE to my computer (Windows 32-bit). But When I open "Get Started with Oracle XE", multiple pages are opened and written "This web page is not available". How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting your computer helps. It's not explicitly listed in the installation procedures but in my experience the web interfaces aren't started at the end of the installation process.

Comment: I have started all of the services. but pages are not available. I cant access home page

Comment: @NatiqSelimzade if you're rebooted your computer already, check if there's another webserver running at port 8080 that blocks the one Oracle XE tries to start from starting properly.

Comment: Unfortunately, everything is ok. ports are different